# Redefine screen split ratios

Tags: screen, snap-windows

I'm not sure of the best way to ask this question because I don't know the correct terminology for what I'm asking about.

When I drag a window to the edge of my screen it automatically resizes to occupy half the width of the monitor. Same with the function key + left/right arrow. They both make the window resize to a 50/50 split for each side.

Now, I have a 26" monitor and I find the best setup when coding is a text editor taking up 75% of the width with a terminal taking up the other 25%.

Is it possible to somehow make it so when I drag against the right side, the window resizes to the right 25% of the monitor, and against the left side the window resizes to 75%?

Surely the 50/50 ratio must be stored somewhere? Can I just edit that to be 25/75? Or an arbitrary ratio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a `25/75` quite easily by activating the "**Cycle Through Multiple Sizes**" option of the Grid Compiz plugin in **CCSM** (CompizConfig Settings Manager):

1. Install **CCSM**, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open CCSM and type **Grid** in the Filter field:

   [image]
3. The plugin to configure is the **Grid** plugin. Open it and select the **Resize Actions** tab:

   [image]
4. Enable the "Cycle Through Multiple Sizes" checkbox and close CCSM.

Now if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> (but <kbd>6</kbd> in the numeric keypad) two times, the window will be on the right side, 25%. 4 times to get a 75%.

Tested OK on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I knew there would be something to do this, just couldn't figure out the right Google terms to find it.